# Write JSON to txt file with formatting

Tags: php, json, formatting

I have content in JSON format. For instance:

`{"rand":"7542868","action":"get","identity":{"name":"Jack","password":"secret"},"key":"o8sh769f79"}` and i know how to decode it. But how to put in into txt file as pretty-formatted like following?

```
{
  "rand":"7542868",
  "action":"get",
  "identity":
  {
    "name":"Jack",
    "password":"secret"
  },
  "key":"o8sh769f79"
}
```

**PHP Version 5.5.27**

I created method:

```
static function ApiLog($type ,$data)
    {
        $data = json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
        $myfile = fopen(__DIR__."/log/".date('Y-m-d').".txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
        $entry = date("H:i:s")." ".$type." ".$data."\n";
        fwrite($myfile, $entry);
        fclose($myfile);
    }
```

input **$type** equals `<-` and **$data** is 
`{"rand":"7542868","action":"get","identity":{"name":"Jack","password":"secret"},"key":"o8sh769f79"}`

but **output** file is

`11:34:23 <- "{\"rand\":\"7542868\",\"action\":\"get\",\"identity\":{\"name\":\"Jack\",\"password\":\"secret\"},\"key\":\"o8sh769f79\"}"`

still inline.

Answer (score 4):

```
$file = fopen("yourfile.txt","w");
fwrite($file, json_encode($data_array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
fclose($file);
```

http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-encode.php

Comment: It should perhaps be noted that this constant `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` is only available in PHP versions 5.4 onwards! ( From the manual: `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT (integer)
    Use whitespace in returned data to format it. Available since PHP 5.4.0.` )

Comment: you have to pass the PHP-array to json_encode, not an already encoded JSON-string. otherwise, you have to decode it first: json_encode(json_decode($data), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);